# Workflow to have character look like : Tokyo ghoul:re [Call to exist]

Tags: unity, 3d, blender, zbrush

I am looking into a lot of different software and now that I got my head around most of them, I was asking mysel if someone knew what has been used to create the characters in the game I mentionned.

Not specifically software if there is no information about it, but at least as it been modeld/sculpted, etc.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Why would making a character for this game be different from modelling a character for any other game? What specific aspect have you had difficulty implementing so far?

Comment: I am having trouble figuring out if it was modeled or sculpted @DMGregory

Comment: Which way have you tried so far? How are the results differing from what you want?